# For loop from a file

Tags: java

I'm trying to get numbers from a file to print out as well as be added together and the total printed. I can only get one or the other to work, but not both. Here's what I have so far:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class ReadFromFile{
    public static void main(String[] args)throws IOException{
        File fp = new File("Java_Output.txt");
        Scanner fs = new Scanner(fp);
        int sum = 0;
        while(fs.hasNext()){    
            System.out.println(fs.nextLine());
            sum += fs.nextInt();
        }
        fs.close();
        System.out.println(sum);
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have a sample input, expected output and actual output for this piece of code?

Comment: Hint: every time you call nextXxx, you read the next Xxx and move the cursor. Calling nextLine() and nextInt() reads a line, and then reads an int *after* this line. Variables are your friends.

Comment: "I can only get one or the other to work, but not both." This is because once you call `fs.nextLine()` the number is taken from the buffer; the following call to `fs.nextInt()` would read the number that follows, or may not have anything to read. Change your code to read each line/number only once, store it in a variable, and use it both for printing and for computing the total.

Comment: How does your txt file looks Like and which Version does Work with your code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you call `fs.nextLine()` you consume an entire line, then you add the `int` from the *next* line to the `sum`. Based on your question, you wanted something like

```
while(fs.hasNextInt()){
    int v = fs.nextInt();    
    System.out.println(v);
    sum += v;
}
```

**Note**: Call `hasNextInt()` before calling `nextInt()`.

Answer (score 1):

When you call `fs.nextLine()` you move the scanner to the next line. Past the first line of the file. 
If your input file,`Java_Output.txt`, is in the form:

```
10
20
30
40
50
```

or

```
10 20 30 40 50
```

This modified version will work:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class ReadFromFile{

    public static void main(String[] args)throws IOException{
        Scanner fs = new Scanner(new File("Java_Output.txt") );
        int sum = 0;
        while(fs.hasNext()){    
            sum += fs.nextInt();
        }
        fs.close();
        System.out.println(sum);
    }

}
```